# How to get the first part of a C String?

Tags: c

I have two strings:

```
prettyCoolString
CoolString
```

I want to only get the part that says `pretty`. I looked through the C string functions, but I cannot find out how to find the position of CoolString in prettyCoolString.

In Java, I can just find where CoolString appears in prettyCoolString, but with C, all I can do is return a pointer to the place where it begins. I want to find the position so I can just read the first x characters from prettyCoolString.

Here is what I mean by first part:
I want to get the contents of the first string that appear before the second string appears in the first string.

Comment: What criteria qualifies `pretty` to be the "first part"?

Comment: What, exactly are you trying to do? You say you have two strings... what does that have to do with the question? Are you trying to find the second within the first?

Comment: [`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
char *source = "prettyCoolString";
char *find = "CoolString";

char dest[LENGTH];
char *p = strstr(source, find);
strncpy(dest, source, p - source);
```

Comment: `strcpy(dest, source, strlen(source) - p)` should be `strncpy(dest, source, p - source)`

Comment: @NiklasHansson I find strncpy harder to use (doesn't always fill in `\0`).

Comment: True, but it only omits the null character if your buffer is too small. You also call strcpy as it would be strncpy. strcpy takes only 2 arguments, destination and source and copies until it finds a null character. If you want to use strcpy, you would have to put a `\0` in `*(p)`

Comment: Here you can see the difference between strcpy and strncpy.
You can also see that I was wrong about the buffer length. strncpy omits the null character when it finds n characters to copy. Since we know that we will find the all n characters, we can just append the null character to the destination buffer at all times.

Answer (score 2):

" all I can do is return a pointer to the place where it begins"
That and the length tells you pretty much all you need.

Use [strstr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/) (or one of it's family) to search for the string if you don't know where it is.

[strncpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/) will copy that part to a new string.

Comment: One step missing: the terminating `\0`.

Comment: strncpy supplies the terminating \0 - mostly, except where it doesn't. Don't you just love 'C' ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a pointer to the first character past the "first part" (which you say you know how to do, presumably with [`strstr`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strstr.htm)), you can use it in several ways to extract the first part into a separate string. For instance:

```
char *substring(char *start, char *stop, char *dst, size_t size)
{
   int count = stop - start;
   if ( count >= --size )
   {
      count = size;
   }
   sprintf(dst, "%.*s", count, start);
   return dst;
}
```